# Cloud servers identification

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I spin up cloud servers in Rackspace very often. They are created and deleted with a php script. The script needs to identify each server. And each server has to know its identity. I mean, I use a database where each server and its status (created, running, deleted, etc) are logged. Both the script and the server write in this database.

I identify each server with its (unique) hostname.

However, when a server is created it doesn't have the correct hostname at the beginning, it needs some time to get the hostname it was launched with. So, at the beginning the server is idle until it can identify itself.

Why? When is the hostname changed (my servers are Ubuntu 14.04)?

Do you know a better alternative to identify the server?

Comment: Why don't you use the UUID for the server? If you go to the server as it appears in the Control Panel, you'll see a long ID.

Comment: @hohner How can the server read its UUID?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You go to the Control Panel and see the associated UUID for that server. If you're using an SDK, there will be a method to do that...